# Django Rest Serializer get data related through Foreign Keys

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have the following model skeletons:

```
class A(models.Model):
    post_id = models.ForeignKey('D')
    user_id = models.ForeignKey('B')

class B(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True)    
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    # `resource_id`
    profile_photo = models.ForeignKey('C', null=True)

class C(models.Model):
    user_id = models.ForeignKey('B')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
```

I want to write a serializer for A which should return `name` from model C, which is related to B.

The relation here is like 
A->B->C
Now using A's serializer I want data to be fetched from C

I want to access C via A i.e get profile_photo from B and the get the name of profile_photo from C

I scrolled through RelatedFields as given here [Django Rest relations](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/) but am not able to achieve what I want.

Is their any way I can achieve it.

Also there are a lot of fields other than mentioned in the model skeleton and I do not want to fetch those.

**EDIT**:
The final result I need is the all the `user_id` for a particular `post_id` from A with the `name` from model C

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a [ModelSerializer](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#modelserializer):

Note: I will asumme that `'posts.Post'` is model `C`

```
class CsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = C
        fields = ('name')


class AsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    post_id = CsSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = A
        # exclude = ('field_you_dont_want_1', 'field_you_dont_want_2')
        # fields = ('field_you_want_1', 'field_you_want_2')
```

Note that in `CsSerializer` you can return any field you want from model `C` in this case I'm just returning a `name`.

If you just need a string, you could use [StringRelatedField](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#stringrelatedfield)

```
class AsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    post_id = serializers.StringRelatedField(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = A
```

This `StringRelatedField` will return what C models return in `__unicode__` method (`__str__` method if python 3.x).

**EDIT**

Now, from your comment, I know that `'posts.Post'` is not `C` model. So you could use [SerializerMethodField](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield):

```
class AsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    c_name = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_c_name(self, obj):
        return obj.user_id.c_set.values('name')  # this will return a list of dicts with B's related C objects.

    class Meta:
        model = A
```

**EDIT**

You can always define class methods in your models:

```
class B(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True)    
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    # `resource_id`
    profile_photo = models.ForeignKey('C', null=True)

    def get_profile_photo(self):
        return self.profile_photo.name  # This will return 'C' related object's name
```

So when you have an A's objects:

```
a_object.user_id.get_profile_photo()
```

Or if you have an B's object:

```
b_object.get_profile_photo()
```

**EDIT**

You can define a new Serializer for C class:

```
class CsSerializer(serializers.Serializer):

    class Meta:
        model = C
```

Then in your `AsSerializer`

```
class AsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    c_name = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_c_name(self, obj):
        qs = obj.user_id.c_set.all()
        qs_serialized = CsSerializer(qs, many=True)
        return qs_serialized.data

    class Meta:
        model = A
```

Comment: Sorry for being unclear, 'posts.Post' is not model C, it is some other model

Comment: @ofnowhereland So you want access to C via B?

Comment: I want to access C via A i.e get profile_photo from B and the get the name of profile_photo from C

Comment: Got it working, but I need to serialize it and queryset may include more than one users , any idea how could that be achieved